# Oracle Apex: Last_updated_by

Tags: oracle-apex

Version 18.
I've always assumed that the last_update_date and last_updated_by on apex pages were maintained when you changed the application. (added/changed code on the pages for example).

I've since discovered that if a user creates an interactive report, it updates that audit info too.
While I understand that Apex saves those reports against the application,  it does made it tricky to know whether the application code has actually changed via the developer or not.

Does anybody know whether there is a setting to not update the last_updated_by in Apex if a user changes interactive reports? It is distortig my ability to see genuine application changes vs saved reports changes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So far as I know there is no such thing. Why is important to you to know this information?

Comment: @EnriqueFlores - All I can think of is for Audit purposes.

Comment: We deploy the same application on multiple sites. Sometimes we make mini-patches (directly edit the application), and then deploy "properly" with the master/product version. As we don't do master deployments too often (it is disruptive), it would be good to have an accurate representation of the last time that a page was updated. To my mind, somebody change an interactive reports is not a genuine application update. Yes it's an off requirement, but Apex is tricky to deploy on multiple sites safely because it can only be deployed in one f(999).sql file.